# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'is_valid_format'

Tags: python, django, email

I want to validate an email by abstractapi. After running api_url and key , the data given below is gotten.

```
    {

  "email": "email@domain.com",
  "autocorrect": "",
  "deliverability": "DELIVERABLE",
  "quality_score": "0.80",
  "is_valid_format": {
    "value": true,
    "text": "TRUE"
  },
  "is_free_email": {
    "value": false,
    "text": "FALSE"
  },
  "is_disposable_email": {
    "value": false,
    "text": "FALSE"
  },
  "is_role_email": {
    "value": false,
    "text": "FALSE"
  },
  "is_catchall_email": {
    "value": true,
    "text": "TRUE"
  },
  "is_mx_found": {
    "value": true,
    "text": "TRUE"
  },
  "is_smtp_valid": {
    "value": true,
    "text": "TRUE"
  }
}
```

when i want to acces the data by this code given below , i found attribute error.  **AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'is_valid_format'**.

```
api_key = '0191f6bdc0eb401a951bfa95f1564210'
api_url = 'https://emailvalidation.abstractapi.com/v1/?api_key=' + api_key

    def validate_email(email):
    
        response = requests.get(api_url + "&email=email")
        data = response.content
    
        if data.is_valid_format.value and data.is_mx_found.value and data.is_smtp_valid.value:
            if not data.is_catchall_email.value and not data.is_role_email.value and not data.is_free_email.value:
                return True
        return False
```

the error is:

```
AttributeError at /send_email
'bytes' object has no attribute 'is_valid_format'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/send_email
Django Version: 4.1.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'bytes' object has no attribute 'is_valid_format'
Exception Location: H:\Python\send_email\app\utils.py, line 16, in validate_email
Raised during:  app.views.send_email
Python Executable:  C:\Users\anupa\anaconda3\envs\Python\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.12
Python Path:    
['H:\\Python\\send_email',
 'C:\\Users\\anupa\\anaconda3\\envs\\Python\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\anupa\\anaconda3\\envs\\Python\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\anupa\\anaconda3\\envs\\Python\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\anupa\\anaconda3\\envs\\Python',
 'C:\\Users\\anupa\\anaconda3\\envs\\Python\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 16 Mar 2024 10:09:49 +0000
```

how i overcome the error?